# Migrating Spring Boot 2.7.0 to 3.0.2, Am facing issue ( jakarta.jms.ConnectionFactory cannot be typecast to com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory)

Tags: spring-boot, type-conversion, integration, ibm-mq

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate]: Factory method 'jmsTemplate' threw exception with message: class com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory cannot be cast to class jakarta.jms.ConnectionFactory (com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory and jakarta.jms.ConnectionFactory are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:171)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653)
    ... 66 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory cannot be cast to class jakarta.jms.ConnectionFactory (com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory and jakarta.jms.ConnectionFactory are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

Issue might be because of IBM MQ is not supporting higher version or not compatible with spring 6 but not sure. looking for the resolution for the issue.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 4):

MQ provides Jakarta-compatible packages. You have to change your dependencies to use the correct module.

If you're using the MQ Spring Boot library, then use the corresponding V3.x.x artifact.

If you are directly referencing the MQ client libraries, then use `com.ibm.mq.jakarta.client` instead of the `com.ibm.mq.allclient`.